# Latex table alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a table of 2 columns, I want the writing in the left column to be centered and the right column to be aligned to the left.

Using the commands below, the left column is exactly how I want it, but the writing in the left column is aligned to the right but I would like to align it to the left. How can I do this?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{cc}

\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Use `\begin{tabular}{cl}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{cc}`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I am getting an error, do I need a certain package to use {c1} instead of {cc}?

Comment: It is the letter "L" (though lowercase), *not* the number one (1). A `c` centers text in a column, an `l` left-aligns it, and an `r` right-aligns it.

Comment: Oh, thanks that really helps. Just one more question: can you tell me how to wrap the text? The text in my right column exceeds the page width. I would appreciate it! :)

Comment: One option is to put stuff inside of a `\parbox` (see [How to wrap text in table cell?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67172/how-to-wrap-text-in-table-cell)), but there are probably other ways, too. Keep in mind that you can always search this site. There's a lot of good information on the site already! At any rate, welcome to TeX.SX! `:)`

Comment: Thanks for everything, very helpful!! :) Much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Column alignment is specified at the beginning of the tabular environment. You currently have `cc` there, which means that there are two columns and both are centered (c = center). To align a column to the left use `l` in place of `c`, and to align it to the right use `r`. If some of your columns contain lots of text, a paragraph column can be used. Then you also have to provide the width of the column, for example you could use `\begin{tabular}{cp{5cm}}`. In your case, if I understood correctly, I would suggest that you try `\begin{tabular}{cl}` instead of `\begin{tabular}{cc}`. If you want more info about tables in LaTeX (for example how to use the handy `\multicolumn` command), check out the [LaTeX wikibook entry on tables](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables).